# Is there a way of having Blender reset the 'origin to geometery' automatically?

Tags: origin, 3d-manipulator

At the moment, when I resize or modify an object, I manually click Set Origin -> Origin to Geometry to recentre the manipulators in the object's bounds.

Like so:

[image]

My desire is to have the origin always centered to the object as it changes. Is there any way of just having Blender do this automatically?

Comment: Never heard of that. Why would you need that feature? Maybe we can think up a workaround? Try binding a shortcut? Alt Shift C or something like that.

Comment: @JudeDesir I'm doing a lot of blockout work for geometry. This involves lots of pieces that I'm constantly resizing, making longer, thinner...etc. My desire is to always have the manipulators positioned at the centre of the object for ease of use. 

It would just save time. Any manual input that is required to reposition the origin is, exactly that, manual input. It extends the workflow. I want to know if there is a more automated way of having Blender help me out so its one less thing I have to constantly do.

Answer (score 1):

**Scripting**

[image]
*Test run, <kbd>Shift</kbd> select 3 objects, extends middle to "kiss" outer*

Test script:

Select 3 objects, extends the active (middle) to the outer objects.  Click the "run script" button to run.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
context = bpy.context

def kiss_faces(ob, target):
    mw = ob.matrix_world
    mwi = ob.matrix_world.inverted()
    v = mwi @ target.matrix_world.translation
    if v.length < 1e-5:
        return 
    f = sorted(ob.data.polygons, key=lambda p : (p.center - v).length)[0]

    pt = target.matrix_world.inverted() @ ob.matrix_world @ f.center
    hit, loc, norm, idx = target.closest_point_on_mesh(pt)  

    if hit:

        d = (ob.matrix_world.inverted() @ target.matrix_world @ loc - f.center).length * f.normal 
        for i in f.vertices:
            ob.data.vertices[i].co += d
        ob.data.update()

o = context.object
a, b = [o for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH' and o is not context.object]
assert(o == context.object)

kiss_faces(o, a)
kiss_faces(o, b)
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY')
```

Note script above for 2.8, for 2.7x, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> [image]in blender text editor and replace all occurrences of  ampersand @ with asterisk *